How to export a temporal forecasting transformer model as an onnx model?
I have a TFT model that is performing a timeseries forecasting using the get_stallion dataset. See the link below for reference:
https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/stallion.html
I am trying to export the model as an onnx model but failing to do so. Could someone please explain how to construct the dummy input and feed it to the onnx model before exporting it?
This is the code I ran:

# Generate a dummy input from the validation dataloader

dummy_batch, _ = next(iter(val_dataloader))



# Prepare the dummy inputs by extracting tensors from the batch dictionary

encoder_cat = dummy_batch["encoder_cat"]

encoder_cont = dummy_batch["encoder_cont"]

decoder_cat = dummy_batch["decoder_cat"]

decoder_cont = dummy_batch["decoder_cont"]

encoder_target = dummy_batch["encoder_target"]

decoder_target = dummy_batch["decoder_target"]

encoder_lengths = dummy_batch["encoder_lengths"]

decoder_lengths = dummy_batch["decoder_lengths"]

decoder_time_idx = dummy_batch["decoder_time_idx"]

groups = dummy_batch["groups"]

target_scale = dummy_batch["target_scale"]



# Prepare the dummy input as a dictionary of inputs

dummy_input = {

   "encoder_cat": encoder_cat,

   "encoder_cont": encoder_cont,

   "decoder_cat": decoder_cat,

   "decoder_cont": decoder_cont,

   "encoder_target": encoder_target,

   "decoder_target": decoder_target,

   "encoder_lengths": encoder_lengths,

   "decoder_lengths": decoder_lengths,

   "decoder_time_idx": decoder_time_idx,

   "groups": groups,

   "target_scale": target_scale

} 

# Wrapping the model to handle dictionary inputs

class WrappedModel(torch.nn.Module):

   def __init__(self, model):

       super(WrappedModel, self).__init__()

       self.model = model



   def forward(self, encoder_cat, encoder_cont, decoder_cat, decoder_cont,

               encoder_target, decoder_target, encoder_lengths, decoder_lengths,

               decoder_time_idx, groups, target_scale):

       # Create the input dictionary

       input_dict = {

           "encoder_cat": encoder_cat,

           "encoder_cont": encoder_cont,

           "decoder_cat": decoder_cat,

           "decoder_cont": decoder_cont,

           "encoder_target": encoder_target,

           "decoder_target": decoder_target,

           "encoder_lengths": encoder_lengths,

           "decoder_lengths": decoder_lengths,

           "decoder_time_idx": decoder_time_idx,

           "groups": groups,

           "target_scale": target_scale

       }

      

       # Pass the inputs to the model

       return self.model(input_dict)



# Instantiate the wrapped model

wrapped_model = WrappedModel(tft)





# Prepare the inputs as a tuple of tensors

dummy_input_tuple = (

   encoder_cat, encoder_cont, decoder_cat, decoder_cont,

   encoder_target, decoder_target, encoder_lengths, decoder_lengths,

   decoder_time_idx, groups, target_scale

)



torch.onnx.export(

   wrapped_model,

   dummy_input_tuple,  # Pass the input tensors as a tuple

   onnx_model_path,

   input_names=list(dummy_input.keys()),

   output_names=["output"],

   dynamic_axes={

       "encoder_cat": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"},

       "encoder_cont": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"},

       "decoder_cat": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"},

       "decoder_cont": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"},

       "encoder_target": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"},

       "decoder_target": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"},

       "encoder_lengths": {0: "batch_size"},

       "decoder_lengths": {0: "batch_size"},

       "decoder_time_idx": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"},

       "groups": {0: "batch_size"},

       "target_scale": {0: "batch_size", 1: "num_features"},

       "output": {0: "batch_size", 1: "sequence_length"}

   },

   opset_version=11  # Specify the ONNX opset version

)



print(f"Model exported to {onnx_model_path}")

The model got exported but when I am starting the onnx runtime session and loading the model again, I saw that some of the input parameters are missing. There could be an issue with the forward method of the TemporalFusionTransformer but I am unable to resolve it. Any pointers please?
